# Run Configuration in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

Hi I'm sure this is a stupid question but I am running eclipse in linux mint 15 and whenever I try to press the main run option in the upper tab of the eclipse menu (next to the build option) I get a message saying systemtap is not installed, and then the run button grays out and I cant use it unless I restart eclipse and run into the same problem. I know this is an issue with the run configuration but when I attempt to alter it in the run configurations menu all that ends up happening is a run button being created in the favorites tab for the particular project I have selected. What I am trying to do is have the main run button launch whichever project I have selected through the default option instead of attempting to automatically use systemtap. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to install the systemtap packages. From a terminal...

```
sudo apt-get install systemtap
```